# Did Minecraft or one of the tweaks mods take away shift-click to move inventory items in bulk?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

In 1.7 modded Minecraft I could have sworn it used to be that:

- Left click an item stack to pick it up
- Hold sneak/shift
- Left click in another inventory, e.g. a chest

This action used to move all of that item into the destination inventory.

Now I'm on 1.12, and it isn't happening.

I have no idea whether it was a Minecraft vanilla thing, or whether it was Inventory Tweaks or Mouse Tweaks doing it, but I still have both of those on 1.12 and it isn't doing it anymore. :/

Does anyone know what used to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably confusing two different Vanilla mechanics:

- If you double-click on an item, you collect up to 64 items of that type on your cursor, even if they were in different stacks.
- If you click one item and then shift-double-click on another, as many items from that other type move into the other inventory as possible. You do not click on an empty space in the other inventory

Of course it's still possible that some mod added a redundant way to do the second thing, but I doubt it, because that would have been redundant (just like that statement).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was even able to hold shift to dump all of a given item out of an inventory onto the floor...

Comment: That would be modded then. The easiest way to find out would be to recreate the modded game you had before, trying it and if it works, taking out mods until it no longer works. Then you know which one caused it and if that mod no longer allows that behaviour in 1.12, you can ask the creator.